# Jquery ajax is calling multiple time on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onscroll

Here in the below code iam calling ajax on scroll.
But this is calling ajax multiple times. To restrict this i added setTimeout function and flag (i.e. isActive) still it is calling two times.
Please help me where iam going wrong.
Thanks in advance

```
var isActive = false;
var sIndex =12;
var myflag = '1';   
var offSet = 12;
var timeout;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
  if(typeof timeout == "number") {
  window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  delete timeout;
 }
timeout = window.setTimeout( check, 500);
});


function check(){
var cat = $(".mi-selected").attr('id');
var tecID = $("#technologyID").val();
    var notSameInd = $("#notSameInd").val();
    var sIndex =$("#startInd").val();
if (!isActive &&  ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) && (sIndex !== notSameInd) ) {
   var isActive = true;
jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'http://some.com/responcePortfolio.php',
              data: {
             tecID:tecID,
                  cat:cat,
                  startIndex:sIndex,
                  offset:offSet,
                  count_now:count_now
               },
              success: function (result) {
            if(result !== ''){
                jQuery("#LoaderImage").hide();
                    jQuery("#portfolioList").append(result);
                $("#notSameInd").val(sIndex);
                    sIndex = parseInt(sIndex) + parseInt(offSet);
                $("#startInd").val(sIndex);
              }
                  else{    
                                   jQuery("#LoaderImage").hide();
               }
            isActive = false;
               },
              error: function (error) {
                  //alert(error);
              }
          });    

}
```

}

Comment: IT seems there is no problem on your code, `check` function called once. You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/CC27B/

Comment: thanks for replay, checking

Comment: it working there but when i use above code, when scroller reaches to end it is bounsing back and calling once again, it is not happening all the times, only some times. Is there any thing wrong, while checking the flag

Comment: Have you got any error on console? And Especially in which case you are getting strange behaviour?

Comment: it is not showing any error in the console, when the scroll reaches to  end iam calling ajax. If some times scorller hits the end point two times, at that time same ajax call is happening multiple times. If no probs, please go through this link and scroll down for results. http://softidsolutions.com/portfolio/

Comment: Could you please try to increase timeout time and try again? You can change 500 to 1000

Comment: yah, i increased to 1000, some times if scrolls again and again same problem happening.

Comment: The logic looks suspect.  Why does it always clear the existing timeout on scroll?  Prefer _.debounce() from underscoreJS.